# Where does the wormhole go?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, wormholes

I'm familiar with the basic idea of what a wormhole (Einstein-Rosen bridge) is and have seen many varied visualizations of what it would perhaps look like if you met one. I have several questions that really have been bothering me for a long time.

Where does the other end of a wormhole lead to when it's created?

When one forms what happens to the end you come out of?

Is it randomly assigned a position in the universe or is there some predictable reason they form at certain places?

Does it connect to a network of other wormholes?

Comment: Thank you @Alfred Centauri .

Comment: Your question is logically reversed. The gravitational equations define the curvature of spacetime created by matter. If you possess exotic matter (like negative mass and such), then the distribution of this matter will fully define your wormhole. You put the other end wherever you want by distributing your exotic matter accordingly. Thus your question cannot be answered as asked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Einstein-Rosen bridge (which you specifically mentioned) tells us that when the singularities of a black hole and 'white hole' merge they form a connection between two regions of space. The wormhole can lead to other universes or even different points in ours. But, it was soon discovered that wormholes between two points in the same universe would be unstable and would collapse due to high gravity. SO, if any wormholes existed it would be between our universe and another parallel universe.

Comment: When exactly do “*the singularities of a black hole and 'white hole' merge*”? They are very much separate on a Penrose diagram.

Comment: “*wormholes between two points in the same universe would be unstable and would collapse due to high gravity*” - Some wormholes have no gravity at all: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_wormhole

Comment: @safesphere I did specifically mention Einstein Rosen bridges

Comment: “*if any wormholes existed it would be between our universe and another parallel universe*” - So, if we take two wormholes, do both lead to the same or different “parallel universes”? How many of them are “out there”? Do they obey the same laws of nature? Do they have the same Standard Model fine tuning parameters? But most importantly, if they are all connected, then how are they not the same universe (spacetime manifold)?

Comment: @safesphere all of this is unproven and exists mathematically. All the question you asked about the 'same laws of nature', 'Standard Model' 'fine tuning' I have no idea, and nor does anybody else. We just know what the math shows us. So, the best way to answer your question: find a wormhole and travel through it.